# .htaccess http_referer rule in certain directory for nginx conf

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, configuration

I have following in .htaccess in specific directory so that I can restrict the download files only so that they can be viewed by player on my site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domain.com/ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.domain.com/ [NC]

RewriteRule [^/]+.(flv)$ - [F]
```

I have searched and tried pretty much everything what I can think of how to do this with nginx but I just can't get it to work. I'm sure it's simple but just have no idea, anyone could help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, you want an *Nginx equivalent* to the Apache ruleset provided.

```
location ~* \.flv$ {
  if ($http_referer !~* ^https?:\/\/(domain.com|www.domain.com).*) {
    return 403;
  }
}
```

Become familiar with these resources as well:

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location
- http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil
- http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule#if

Comment: Thank you so much! This sorted it out indeed. You definitely made my day :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked first shot. Be sure you read those resources, too, though.

Comment: Absolutely will, thanks again. Just going through the "ifisevil" link, hope I'm not going to have any probs with it.